# Giving back to the PSE Community: Rebus Connect Wall

Tags: rhyme, rebus, seasonal, connect-wall

Here comes a rebus connect wall dedicated to the PSE Community. You'll soon see why ;)

[image]

Steps:

1. Solve the 16 rebuses!
2. Group them into groups of 4!
3. You're done!

Disclaimer:

> If anyone find this offending, please mention in the comments. Apologies in advance!

PS:

> For easy reference, please number the images as follows, according to their respective positions:
>
> 1 2 3(solved) 4(solved)
>
> 5 6(solved) 7 8
>
> 9(solved) 10(solved) 11(solved) 12(solved)
>
> 13(solved) 14(solved) 15 16

Thanks and enjoy!

---

**HINTS:**

Overall Categories:

> For few I am a mirror, 
> For some in your eye. 
> For more I am one of your decorations, 
> and all near the border!

The following hints refer to 1 or more images in the range:

1~4:

> My alpha is a twisted nil, 
> My omicron oft beguiled. 
> My omega asks me favour this why, 
> But lo! Simple and sweet am I.

This hint refers to image no:

> 1

6~8:

> Be well convinced, 
> My future ain't bright. 
> Alter your vision, 
> And you'll see me right.

This hint refers to image no:

> 7

9~12:

> You raise me up, so I can stand on mountains
> You raise me up to walk on stormy seas
> I am strong when I am on your shoulders
> You raise me up to more than I can be

This hint refers to image no:

> 9 & 10

13~16:

> The truth unveiled, 
> The falses revealed, 
> Just bear in mind,
> What's going on behind...
> [image]

This hint refers to image no:

> 16

Hint on category:

> Pay attention to the **tags** of the question >;) 
>  and sadly, the puzzle has become harder to solve now because of the **time**... 
>  perhaps this would make it easier to solve the rebus?

Giveaway: (NO LONGER USEFUL)

> cesy cp

Hint on unsolved rebuses:

> 1: Fixes
> 2. Katniss
> 5.
> 7. Simply ROTATE!
> 8. %:%:%
> 15: toilet
> 16: rf-gt-b?

NOTE:

> The [rhyme](/questions/tagged/rhyme) tag is there just because of the hints

Comment: the little stroke next to image 4 was not intended, please leave it alone. thanks!

Comment: **This** comment is for hint request. pls upvote this comment if you need a hint. I will use this as a reference for when i should give a hint to you all. thanks!

Comment: **This new comment** is for hint request from now on. pls upvote this comment if you need a hint. I will use this as a reference for when i should give a hint to you all. A new comment is posted as previously upvoted users may want a hint again, and they may upvote this hint. Thanks!

Comment: no, r13: qrhfbiv vf abg va gur erohfrf pbm v qhaab ubj gb chg uvz vagb n erohf kc @JonMarkPerry

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I didn't unupvote, but to give my honest opinion, I think the puzzle is really under-clued (of course I might just be missing something obvious). Most of the rebuses are just pictures hinting at a word, and in most cases there are multiple possibilities for that word. The hints relating to particular images are more like riddles in themselves, and they really haven't helped me at all. Even knowing what the categories are, I haven't been able to figure out all the words you have in mind (again, might just be because I've missed a bunch of things). Just my thoughts.

Comment: @Volatility thanks for telling me this, i am really in need of sincere comments... i'll try to do better on my next rebus, if i have one... thanks, but please do try to finish this... i dont want to waste my 50 rep bounty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Intended Answer:

Categories: (@ Volatility got it)

> Each of the pictures is a rebus for one of the following things on the border of the PSE site:
> - the question tags on PSE.
> - the users on PSE.
> - the links on the bar on the top of the site
> - a hat from Winter Bash 2018

Rebuses:

> 1: @Riley (referring to the Riley puzzle format)
> 2: Peacekeeper hat (It is the peacekeeper logo in Hunger Games)
> 3: Inbox (Google Inbox logo)
> 4: @hexomino
> 5: Community
> 6: Gonna Find Out (Santa Hat)
> 7: Liar (by rotating your had, you can see the word in cursive ;) )
> 8: Probability (a pie chart)
> 9: Achievements
> 10: Help
> 11: Pattern (tessellation)
> 12: Rebus (2x buses)
> 13: @Rand al'Thor (random + lightning (thor) )
> 14: Pizza hat
> 15: Clean-up Duty (tissue paper)
> 16: @xnor (hardest one) (blue: boolean operator, green: true, red: false)

Groups:

> Users: 1, 4, 13, 16
> Hats in Winter Bash 2018: 2, 6, 14, 15
> Logos in Top Bar: 3, 5, 9, 10
> Tags in PSE: 7, 8, 11, 12

Hope you guys enjoy it!

Answer (score 5):

### Partial answer

> Each of the pictures is a rebus for one of the following things on the border of the PSE site:
>  - the [question tags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags) on PSE.
>  - the [users](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users) on PSE.
>  - the links on the bar on the top of the site
>  - a [hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list) from Winter Bash 2018

The solutions (tentative):

> ?, IDENTIFICATION DIVISION, Inbox, @hexomino
>  ?, Gonna Find Out, ?, ?
>  Achievements, Help, ?, [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus)
>  @rand al'thor, Pizza Hat, [letters](/questions/tagged/letters), ?

The only connect:

> there are four rebuses which clue items from the four categories listed above; this gives the groupings.

Comment: (hopefully) more specific and may help to solve all rebuses: ROT13(gurl ner gur gbc 4: gbc 4 hfref, gbc 4 gntf, rgp.)

Comment: Perhaps the bottom right could be [tag:rubiks-cube]

Comment: @aguy nice try but no, see hint 13-16 :)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton a pointer might be useful. Will it be obvious when I have the right solution for each rebus?

Comment: yes, the wall is very easy to solve

Comment: 8/16 now, categories correct, keep it up!

Comment: 7: ebgngr 2: ccy sz qvf mreb va UT ol FP

Comment: The first image could be mathematics, and image 11 could be pattern.

Comment: 11 well done! @Nomis

Comment: @Volatility want a hint?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I don't think I'm gonna get anywhere without one...

Comment: @Volatility I dont want to waste the bounty so I am gonna give it to you anyways,. i have upvoted your answer as well. however, i will post my original answer, and accept it later. stay tuned!